# Add transparency to Bitmap image

Tags: android

I have converted my color image to black and white as follow.

```
        //convert color to black&white
        private Bitmap convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(Bitmap orginalBitmap) {
            ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
            colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
            ColorMatrixColorFilter colorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(
                    colorMatrix);
            Bitmap blackAndWhiteBitmap = orginalBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColorFilter(colorMatrixFilter);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(blackAndWhiteBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(blackAndWhiteBitmap, 0, 0, paint);        


            return blackAndWhiteBitmap;
        }
```

How can I add half transparency, about 50% transparency, to the black and white image?
Thanks

Comment: `ARGB` stands for: **alpha**, red, blue and green. So, set your Paint and fill color accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BitmapDrawable bd =
    new BitmapDrawable(convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(bMap));
bd.setAlpha(50);
imageView1.setImageDrawable(bd);
```

Comment: BitmapDrawable has warning as deprecated.

Comment: Alright just modify a bit as BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), convertColorIntoBlackAndWhiteImage(scaledBitmap));